# Can't get NewMessage event on SuperGroup (SelfBot)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telethon

I'm trying to listen to supergroup new messages, but I can't seem to be able to:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import events, utils
from telethon.tl.types import InputMessagesFilterPhotos

api_id = 98.....
api_hash = 'acbc55199.....'
num = '+921.......'
client = TelegramClient(num, api_id, api_hash)

client.connect()

if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(num)
    client.sign_in(num, input('Code: '))

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=[-123456789]))
async def handler(event):
    print(event.from_id.user_id)
```

It works on group I created and channels/groups I'm a member in, but it doesn't for supergroups.
Any idea if I'm doing anything wrong?